# DataRow casting its elements to string?

Tags: c#, wpf, object, datatable, datarow

I am trying to get my objects into a DataTable to use it as ItemsSource of a DataGrid.

```
foreach (Translate t in item.Translations)
{
      if (rowArray[t.IdSprache] == null)
      {
          rowArray[t.IdSprache] = t; //here I add the Translate objects to the object[]
      }
      }
      dt.Rows.Add(rowArray); //adding the object[] to the DataTable
      var test = dt.Rows[cnt].ItemArray[1] as Translate; //aaaaaaaaaaaaaaand the object is gone (test is always null)
      cnt++; 
}
```

Everything works fine, but if i want to cast the elements of the DataRow back to Translate-Objects, i always get `null`.

If I look into the Row's `ItemArray` I only see the objects as string (`Assembly.Type`) not as `Translate` objects.

Does anyone know a workaround/solution for this?

Comment: What's that extra closing brace doing at the end of your `if` statement? And how do you know that `t.IdSprache` was 1?

Comment: Use your immediate window and type `?dt.rows[cnt].ItemArray[1].GetType()` and see the output?

Comment: `I am trying to get my objects into a DataTable to use it as ItemsSource of a DataGrid.` - If you already have a collection of objects, don't use a `DataTable`. The WPF DataGrid doesn't need an ADO.Net DataTable to bind to and can be bound to any `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: @JonSkeet just an copy-and-paste mistake (removed the else part, because its not relevant). `var test = dt.Rows[cnt].ItemArray[1] as Translate;` was only for testing purposes, and in this test t.IdSprache was 1.

Comment: @LukeHennerley the output was System.String! (but why?)

Comment: @HighCore Ok, i'm going to use an IEnumerable<T>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the built in functions on the `DataSet` to create the schema and rows. Something like:

```
Translate t1 = new Translate() { IdSprache = 0 };
Translate t2 = new Translate() { IdSprache = 3 };
Translate t3 = new Translate() { IdSprache = 7 };
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("C" + i, typeof(Translate)));
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr[i] = new Translate() { IdSprache = i };
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        if (dt.Rows[i][j] as Translate != null)
            Console.Write("T");
        else
            Console.Write("N");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Prints

TNNNN
NTNNN
NNTNN
NNNTN
NNNNT

Comment: I didnt notice the second overload of dt.Columns.Add() where you can set the datatype. Thanks, that was it, now I'm getting Translate objects. :)

Comment: @FlorianGI still, this code is dirty and error prone. I insist, DO NOT use ADO.Net DataTables when binding the WPF DataGrid to your objects.

Comment: @HighCore Its dirty because its an example O_o? Why should you not bind a `DataTable` to a `DataGrid` when `DataTable`s are one of the fastest and easiest structures to use for this sort of thing.

Comment: @FlyingStreudel `fastest and easiest structures` - Sorry but I disagree. A DataTable is basically a `Dictionary` with some other features, where you have to use things like `["ColumnName"]` to access the data. These sort of `magic strings` stuff can't stand beside a properly modelled `Object Model` to represent data.

Comment: @HighCore Please look into strongly typed `DataTable`s. They expose properties that can be bound to as well as providing notification methods.

Comment: @FlyingStreudel Why would I want to do that? Do you realize that [`DataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) is a class defined in `System.Data`?? Why would I want to tie my CLIENT application to that? [It doesnt even exist in WinRT (for example)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/4d0e4e5e-2897-44e2-a484-d4a6b9f8e423)